# How can I set a category link to show a custom page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, breadcrumbs

everyone!
So, I'm using a BreadCrumbs, the code is this:

```
//====== BreadCrumbs
function my_breadcrumbs() {
if(!is_front_page()) {
    echo '<nav class="breadcrumb">';
    echo 'Você está aqui: <a href="'.home_url('/').'">'."Início".'</a><span class="divider"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        the_category(' <span class="divider"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> ');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo ' <span class="divider"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> ';
            the_title();
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }
    echo '</nav>';
    }
}
```

But I have a custom template page to show each category and when I'm in a post from a specific category, the BreadCrumbs show the link from category (returning a Not found page when clicked). I would like to know if there is a way to change this to call my custom template page. If so, how could I do this?

Comment: The standard way of using dedicated category template files is by adding their ID to the name of the file. For example: category-18.php (if that is what your theme is using). WP sould automatically look for this file when the breadcrumb has a link to that category.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP file like category-categoryname.php and put in child themes function.php and put below code in the file ( eg:- documentation )

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="section">
                <div class="section_wrapper clearfix">
                    <?php
                        echo '<div class="posts_wrapper clearfix">';    


                            $current_category = get_the_category();
                            $current_category_id = $current_category[0]->cat_ID;

                            foreach( get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'child_of' => 78 ,'orderby' => 'count' , 'order' => 'DESC')) as $cat ) :
                                 echo '<ul class="qa col-md-12"><li class="qa_category"><h2><strong><a style="color:#000;" href="' . get_category_link( $cat ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></h2></strong></li>';
                                 process_cat_tree( $cat->term_id );
                             endforeach;

                             wp_reset_query(); //to reset all trouble done to the original query

                            function process_cat_tree( $cat ) {



                            $args = array(
                                 'category__in' => array( $cat ),
                                 'numberposts' => 6,
                                 'tax_query'     => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                                        'field'     => 'id',
                                                        'terms'     => 77,
                                                    ),
                                ));
                             $cat_posts = get_posts( $args );

                             if( $cat_posts ) :

                             echo '<div class="col-md-6">';  
                             echo '<h6> Documentation </h6>'; 
                             foreach( $cat_posts as $post ) :
                             echo '<li class="qa">';
                             echo '<a style="color: #158ec2;" href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
                             echo '</li>';
                             endforeach;
                             if(count($cat_posts)>5)
                                 echo '<a class="see-all-articles" href="' . get_category_link( $cat ) . '"> See all Articles </a>&nbsp;<br/>';
                             echo '</div>';
                             endif;


                             $next = get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent=' . $cat);

                             if( $next ) :
                             foreach( $next as $cat ) :
                             echo '<ul  class="qa"><li class="qa_category"><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong></li>';
                             process_cat_tree( $cat->term_id );
                             endforeach;
                             endif;

                             echo '</ul>';
                            }


                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```